# how to select running events bewteen selected date range?

Tags: php, mysql

I have events table. I want to get all event records which are running between searched dates.

```
Event Table

id     title     start_date_time          end_date_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      xyz       2014-08-12 11:40:00      2014-08-23 10:30:00
2      pqr       2014-09-05 11:40:00      2014-09-25 09:20:00
3      abc       2014-10-10 11:40:00      2014-10-25 10:00:00
```

For example, I searched for events which are running between 2014-08-15 and 2014-09-10.

Expected result would be :

```
id     title     start_date_time          end_date_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      xyz       2014-08-12 11:40:00      2014-08-23 10:30:00
2      pqr       2014-09-05 11:40:00      2014-09-25 09:20:00
```

So what will be the query to get expected result?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: This question lacks evidence of any effort

Comment: @Strawberry I tried lot to get expected result by my effort but I was unable to get exact result that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `$startdate` and `$enddate`, then you want this `where` clause for overlaps:

```
select e.*
from events e
where $startdate <= e.end_date_time and
      $enddate >= e.start_date_time;
```

The choice of `<=` or `<` depends on whether the end dates are included or not in the event times.

The logic is simple:  there is an overlaps if the event starts before the period ends and ends after the period starts.